# Get Different Images from one URL

Tags: html, css, image, url, random

For example,

http://placeimg.com/640/480/people

is one url. If you reload the page, it comes with a new image.  My website has a background image, and I want it to be a random image of two images:

http://bit.do/bgimage1

http://bit.do/bgimage2

How can I achieve this? And the calling of the image in the css.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: The codepens you linked to look like they would work, but they aren't actually setting the `background-image` css, they're setting an `href`. The random image urls they're generating also don't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript

```
function setRandomImg(){
var items = ['url','url']
var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
document.getElementById(id-of-your-body/container).style.background-image='url('+item+')'
}
```

And add onload to container (example `<body onLoad='setRandomImg()'>`)

Comment: I get this error: "Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

Comment: Nevermind, thanks!